# Setting email attachment name using TIdMessageBuilderHtml

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy

I'm trying to attach a PDF document to an email using Delphi (D10S) and I'd like to set the name to something other than the name of the file on the file system.

I found the following thread (from 2011) where Remy Lebeau states that you can achieve this by setting the `Name` property of the `TIdMessageBuilderAttachment` object when attaching them to the email using the `TIdMessageBuilderHtml`:

> [How to name attachment files constructed by TIdMessageBuilderHtml](http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.winsock/how-to-name-attachment-files-const/1072516)

However, as simple as that sounds, it does not seem to work for me. The email comes through, but the attachment comes through with the original file name, not the one I've specified.

The following is a snippet of code that I expect to do as I've described but, for whatever reason, does not. In this case, I'd like the filename to come through as `desired_filename.pdf`, but it comes through as `undesired_filename.pdf`. I've removed the mail server credentials for obvious reasons:

```
procedure TForm4.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FMessageBuilder : TIdMessageBuilderHtml;
  FSMTP : TIdSMTP;
  FMessage : TIdMessage;
  FAttachment : TIdMessageBuilderAttachment;
begin
  FMessage := TIdMessage.Create();
  FMessageBuilder := TIdMessageBuilderHtml.Create;
  FSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create;

  FAttachment := FMessageBuilder.Attachments.Add('c:\undesired_filename.pdf');
  FAttachment.Name := 'desired_filename.pdf';
  FMessageBuilder.FillMessage(FMessage);

  FMessage.Sender.Address := '<Insert Sender Address>';
  FMessage.Sender.Name := '<Insert Sender Name>';
  FMessage.From.Address := '<Insert From Address>';
  FMessage.From.Name := '<Insert From Name>';
  FMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := '<Insert Recepient Address>';
  FMessage.Subject := 'Attachment Test';

  FSMTP.Host := '<Insert Mail Host>';
  FSMTP.Username := '<Insert Username>';
  FSMTP.Password := '<Insert Password>';
  FSMTP.Connect;
  FSMTP.Send(FMessage);
  FSMTP.Disconnect;
end;
```

I've tested this in D10S and XE and both do the same. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdMessageBuilderAttachment` has both `FileName` and `Name` properties.  When adding an attachment to the builder, those values get assigned to the corresponding properties of the `TIdAttachment` object that gets added to the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` collection.

If an attachment has a `Name` assigned, the value is placed in the `name` attribute of the `Content-Type` header, eg:

```
Content-Type: media/type; name="desired_filename.pdf"
```

If an attachment has a `FileName` assigned, the value is placed in the `filename` attribute of the `Content-Disposition` header, eg:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="undesired_filename.pdf"
```

If both headers are present, conforming readers will give `Content-Disposition` priority when looking for the filename.  That is why your reader is displaying the undesired filename.

When adding a physical file to the builder, `TIdMessageBuilderAttachment` does not currently allow you to specify a different `FileName` than the real file.  This is because `TIdMessageBuilderAttachment` is not the one actually loading the file.  It merely creates a new `TIdAttachmentFile` object and assigns its `FileName` to that object, so it needs the real filename otherwise the attachment will fail to load when sending the email.  However, `TIdAttachmentFile` does allow its own `FileName` to be customized after creation.  It has a separate `StoredPathName` property to keep track of the physical file, so its `FileName` can be whatever you want it to be.

In @fantaghirocco's example, adding a `TStream` to the builder causes a `TIdAttachmentMemory` to be added to `TIdMessage` instead of a `TIdAttachmentFile`.  Since no physical file is involved, the attachment's `FileName` can be anything you want it to be.

So, `TIdMessageBuilderAttachment` will have to be updated to allow setting a physical file attachment's `FileName` separate from its `StoredPathName`.  In the meantime, you can manually update the `TIdAttachmentFile.FileName` property after the `TIdMessage` is filled, eg:

```
FAttachment := FMessageBuilder.Attachments.Add('c:\undesired_filename.pdf');
FAttachment.Name := 'desired_filename.pdf';
FMessageBuilder.FillMessage(FMessage);

for I := 0 to FMessage.MessageParts.Count-1 do
begin
  if FMessage.MessageParts[I].PartType = mptAttachment then
    FMessage.MessageParts[I].FileName = FMessage.MessageParts[I].Name;
end;
```

---

**UPDATE:**

After this answer was first posted, the issue has been addressed by the addition of a new `WantedFileName` property in the `TIdMessageBuilderAttachment` class.

You can set `WantedFileName` to whatever you want, and it will be assigned to the attachment's `FileName` property when populating the `TIdMessage`.  If the `WantedFileName` is blank, then the `TIdMessageBuilderAttachment.FileName` property will be used instead, as before.

Also, the `WantedFileName` will be used if the `TIdMessageBuilderAttachment.Name` property is blank, too.  So, you can now set the desired name in one place, and it will be used for both the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers if needed, eg:

```
FAttachment := FMessageBuilder.Attachments.Add('c:\undesired_filename.pdf');
FAttachment.WantedFileName := 'desired_filename.pdf';
FMessageBuilder.FillMessage(FMessage);
```

No more need to manually update the `TIdAttachment.FileName` property after filling the `TIdMessage`.

Comment: Wow, I never expected you to come and answer this! Thanks! If setting the 'name' property on 'TIdMessageBuilderAttachment' only updates the 'Content-Type' header but the 'Content-Disposition' (populated my 'FileName') takes priority, does that mean the example you gave in the thread I linked would have this same problem, or is there some subtle difference that I've missed? I just presumed that worked as he seemed happy with your answer.

Comment: The earlier example would suffer from the same problem. It is a limitation of `TIdMessageBuilder` that I didn't take into account when I first wrote it, so I will have to make an update to it to account for this, probably with a new property.

Comment: Has this been fixed in recent Delphi versions?

Comment: @SteveKramer yes, it has.  I have updated the answer above with details.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `TIdMessageBuilderAttachments.Add` overload which accepts a `TStream` and setting the `TIdMessageBuilderAttachment.FileName` property to the desired name does the trick for me on *XE4*, *Indy* 10.6.0.4975.

```
stream := TFileStream.Create('c:\undesired_filename.pdf', fmOpenRead);
FAttachment := FMessageBuilder.Attachments.Add(stream, 'application/pdf');
FAttachment.FileName := 'desired_filename.pdf';
```

Comment: That works, thanks!

However, I'm still slightly curious to know what was wrong with the method I was using. I'll wait to see if anyone else can figure it out before I mark this as the answer (I also don't have enough reputation to +1 this yet, but I would if I could).

Comment: @Adam you're welcome, consider this as a workaround until `@Remy will address your issue

Comment: One problem with this approach is that this overload causes the input `TStream` data to be copied into memory (a `TIdAttachmentMemory` object is added to the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` collection), so this is not advisable for large attachments.

Comment: I've marked Remy's answer as accepted as it offers a solution as well as explaining why my method did not work. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Adam there's no problem at all, it's how SO is intended to be used. You did it right, thanks ;)